# Как подключать библиотеки через Composer в NetBeans IDE(PHP)?

Tags: php, netbeans, библиотеки, composer

Собственно, в процессе поиска ответа наткнулся на [оракловскую доку в стиле "берешь и подключаешь"](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/add_project_dependency_via_composer).

Но у меня в окне добавления зависимостей никаких библиотек нет, получается надо было либо их где-то прописывать сперва, либо куда-то класть, либо я вообще в-общем заблудился.

Версия IDE 8.0.2.

И заодно хотелось бы узнать как после подключения через компоновщик правильно подключать библиотеку непосредственно в коде, прежде чем хватать из неё функции посредством `use`

Всё это надо для работы с [pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk), когда прописывал её в `php.ini` и подключал посредством `include` выходила какая-то черепаха, хочу попробовать подключить правильно. `Composer.json` в файлах библиотеки есть.

Answer (score 1):

Работаю с composer'Ом около трех лет и еще никогда мне не были нужны визуальные инструменты в ide, они слишком бедны.

А для использования библиотек загружаемых при помощи composer'а, если быть кратким, то нужно сделать include 'vendor/autoload.php' и после этой строчки начинать пользоваться библиотекой. На гитхабе в репозитории библиотеки есть примеры

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, думал уж совсем вопрос затерялся. Мне не столько уже интересен способ ради визуализации, сколько в принципе почему он не работает(в то время когда подключение через командную строку IDE работает). Из-за этого складывается впечатление что что-то в самой NetBeans не настроено и может "гадить" впоследствие непонятными багами.

Comment: @Ярослав тут я не смогу подсказать, так как никогда не пользовался netbeans. Но могу сказать что такой плагин делают "для галочки", и в нем могут быть баги )